How to open python .exe files with others laptop?
I build a GUI with python and convert that python script into executable file by using auto py to exe. In my laptop it is working fine. If I share that executable file with someone else, it shows some error like file not found. Because some logo's images are updated from my laptop. How to solve this issue?
How will be the files are moved with .exe file?

To do this please include image files (like logos) with your .exe, place them in the same folder as your Python script and use relative paths in your code. When using auto-py-to-exe, ensure you specify these files in the "Additional Files" section to bundle them with the executable.
